# Only first element in ng-repeat is being animated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Attempting to animate an enter/leave on an ng-repeat. The issue I am having is that only the first element is being animated upon the enter state. However, upon leaving, all the repeated items animate out correctly.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataset" class="animate-results">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class-odd="'results-odd'" ng-class-even="'results-even'" >
       <h3 ng-class-odd="'results-heading-odd'" ng-class-even="'results-heading-even'" class="list-group-item-heading">{{data.title}}</h3>
       <p class="list-group-item-text" ng-class-odd="'results-heading-odd'" ng-class-even="'results-heading-even'"><b>Completion Date</b>: {{data.completion_date}} / <b>Score</b>: {{data.score}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.results-heading-even {
    color:#333 !important;
}
.results-heading-odd {
    color:#FFF !important;
}

.animate-results.ng-enter, 
.animate-results.ng-leave{
  -webkit-transition:2s linear all;
  transition:2s linear all;
}

.animate-results.ng-enter,
.animate-results.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity:0;
}


.animate-results.ng-leave,
.animate-results.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you can, try to replicate your issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1ms8X0WnVVgYRzfuTJjt?p=preview

Comment: I have updated the plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gFLaUf?p=preview; It is functioning as you would expect, so it must be something else in my code. I am using bootstrap and the data is being loaded via $http.jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, putting a delay on the response from the server resolves the issue:

```
    $timeout(function(){

      $scope.dataset = response;

    },250);
```

Comment: I had the same problem with angular 1.2.16, updating to 1.2.18 fixed this problem for me

Comment: I had the same problem, but updating to 1.2.21 didn't solve the problem for me. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978191/734040) solved my problem.