# AngularJS only first element in ng-repeat animates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

For some reason using the code below, ngRepeat only animates the first item and displays the rest instantly. As soon as the `scope.categories` item is updated the ng-repeat is triggered in the template.

```
dataSource.getCategories()
    .then(function(categories) {
        $scope.categories = categories;
    }, function(message) {
        dataSource.setActivity(false, message);
    });
```

But if I change the code to the one below and add `<a ng-click="start()">Start</a>` in the page, it works. Yes, I have tried $timeout, even up to 5 seconds and it does not change the situation.

```
dataSource.getCategories()
    .then(function(categories) {
        $scope.start = function() {
            $scope.categories = categories;
        }

    }, function(message) {
        dataSource.setActivity(false, message);
    });
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I'm using the latest as of post entry. 1.2.9

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS.

Comment: HTML is here (bottom, nav.boxes): https://github.com/backslashed/room24/blob/master/templates/page.html
CSS here: https://github.com/backslashed/room24/blob/master/styles/sass/_animations.scss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your CSS with AngularJS 1.2.9 and got the same result. It works with 1.2.13 however.
There have been so many changes to the ngAnimate module in the 1.2.*-branches so without digging deeper into the matter my guess is it's a bug that has since been fixed.

**Demo - 1.2.9 not working**: http://plnkr.co/edit/WvK2DDB6wTUkjx4Ah2bs?p=preview

**Demo - 1.2.13 working**: http://plnkr.co/edit/50UdTAKAsua85hyLc1O6?p=preview

Comment: Wow man! Thanks for taking the time to do that :) I would've never thought! I will try that as soon as I get home after work. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm using 1.2.18 and experiencing this. Perhaps it was re-introduced?

Comment: Able to replicate it in a Plunker? I wouldn't mind taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue (with Angular 1.2.21). My issue was that I was using `!important` on the `transition: all 1s linear` style. Try removing that and see if it works. If you needed `!important` in the first place, try simplifying your CSS.

Here's some plunkers to illustrate the issue I had:

- with `!important` http://plnkr.co/edit/T1Q8DYtNJ6NYvRtrFk10?p=preview
- without `!important` http://plnkr.co/edit/pftzeR1gDmKTgSnvGLgd?p=preview